# What is the easiest way to determine the list of all strings up to length N accepted by DFA or regular expression?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, automata, regular-language, regular-expressions

For example I have the next simple regular expression: `(11|0)+`

It is clear that size of the set of strings that match with this regular expression is infinite: `011,110,11011, 11011011...`

The size of a set of all binary strings with length less then or equal 8 is `N=2^8+2^7...` How to determine the size of subset of the strings that match with provided regular expression? How to get all these strings?

What is the general algorithm for any regular expression / DFA to determine such subset?

Comment: In this case I think you can find the number of matching strings using the recursive sequence $f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-2), f(0) = 1, f(1) = 2$ because basically to get to a string of length $n$ we either have to have a string of length $n - 1$ and add a 0 to the end or have a string of length $n-2$ and add 11 to the end. So funnily enough this regex follows the Fibonacci sequence and $f(8) = 34.$ I don't know if this kind of method extends to all regular expressions though.

Comment: @StephenDonovan I used (11|0)+ to add minimal regularities. Indeed funny coincidence to see a number of strings follows Fibonacci.

Comment: One way to think about this is think about the regular expression as a DFA instead. Then, if we focus on an accepting state, we want the number of paths of length at most N from s to the accepting state, and then we take the sum over all accepting states. This is not an easy calculation, especially is the DFA is not a DAG. In fact, for general graphs, this problem is #P-Complete, as you can see here: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/25707/the-complexity-of-counting-simple-paths-in-a-directed-graph

Comment: @Istorian The link is for counting simple paths, which is a much harder problem since it requires the vertices to be distinct.  The number of walks from one state to another is a simple matter of matrix multiplication.